# Speeding up mysql inner query

Tags: mysql

I currently have:

`SELECT ads, id as mid, (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) FROM trans WHERE paidout=0 AND user_id=mid) as amount FROM accounts`

How could I execute the inner sum query and then go through it and put together the balances in the same manner?

Comment: Use a JOIN, and a GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery will be execute for each row returned. If you convert it into a `LEFT JOIN`, it will be executed once and should be drastically faster.

```
SELECT
  ads,
  id AS mid,
  COALESCE(amount, 0) AS amount
FROM
  accounts
  LEFT JOIN (
    /* Subquery returns SUM(amount) per user_id */
    /* LEFT JOIN in case there are no matching records */
    SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM trans
    WHERE paidout = 0  
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) amt ON accounts.id = amt.user_id
```

The `SUM()` can be done in the outer query in your case as well, applying the `GROUP BY` over all other columns.

```
SELECT 
  accounts.ads, 
  accounts.id AS mid
  COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) AS amount
FROM
  accounts
  LEFT JOIN trans ON accounts.id = trans.user_id
WHERE trans.paidout = 0
GROUP BY
  accounts.ads,
  mid
```

Comment: Unknown column 'mid' in 'on clause'

Comment: @user3287662 Use `accounts.id = amt.user_id`

Comment: Wow, much complex, very gratitude, so speed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT ads, accounts.id as mid, ifnull(sum(amount),0) as amount
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN trans ON paidout=0 AND user_id=accounts.id
GROUP BY accounts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only have two selects VS (1+(num of rows in amount)) selects, as you have it today.

```
select ads, mid, IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) as total
from (
    SELECT a.ads, a.id as mid, amount
    from accounts a
    join trans t on t.user_id = a.id and t.paidout = 0
)
group by ads, mid
```